# jQuery ajaxForm Plugin - submit value from beforeSend callback result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, plugins

I'm using [this jQuery ajaxForm plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) to upload files to my server and also show the progress of the file uploads (as it is primarily for video uploads). I've got this all working fine how I want it to, however I can't figure out how to achieve what I'm trying to do.

So what I want to be able to do is this:

1. submit form - create new row in database
2. return the uniqueID from that and submit it with the file upload

The reason I need/want to do this is because when someone uploads a video I want to let them fill out the video details (Video title, description, etc) and save those while the video is still uploading. So to do this I need to create a row in the database so that it creates that video's unique ID, then return that value to the video upload itself so it can modify that row with the video upload details, and also use that unique id so when the user saves the video information it knows which video it's going to.

```
$('.upload-page form.video-upload').ajaxForm({
url: "ajax/upload.php",
data: {videoID: "videoID"}, //would I be able to modify this from beforeSend?
beforeSend: function() {

//This would be where I would make an ajax call to create the row in the database
    //then i would need to return the value from here to the upload form somehow?   

},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {

    //returns back video upload progress
},
complete: function(xhr) {

           //Upload complete        

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would either try using jquery's append to add  `<input type="hidden" value"(id)" name="video_id" />` to the form or serialize the form and add the id to the end of the string.

However, depending on how you're processing the video upload on the other end you might not be able to get the id before the upload is complete. I've never done something like this with a larger file.